# Barcode scanning windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm looking for a barcode scan library for Windows phone 8.

The biggest problem I'm facing it have to be fully managed since it must be send to Store and all the porting we cand find around seems to rely on native code libraries.

The library should scan both 1D and 2D barcodes.

Stefano

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Zebra Crossing** is a very popular open source barcode scanning library.

The .net port is available from http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/ and does include support from Windows Phone 8.

Comment: thanks I just dowlnoded, it seems to match for what I need

Comment: will these API work for scanning OR code also?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still on the lookout, you can take a look at Manatee Works's [mobiScan mobile barcode sanner SDK](http://manateeworks.com/home). It is closed source though and supports Windows Phone 8+